# Unable to install gazebo 9.13

Tags: installation, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To be able to use the actors with collision plugin I need install Gazebo 9.13. To do so it seems like I have to use the following command, based on [this](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/24778/plugins-in-gazebo-9-ros-melodic/) other issue:

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo9=9.13.0-1*
```

This doesn't appear to work for me however, despite working for the other author. I also tried to write the following command, as suggested by another issue, but without any luck:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gazebo9=9.13.0-1*
```

Error message:

```
ros@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gazebo9=9.13.0-1*
[sudo] password for ros: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '9.13.0-1*' for 'gazebo9' was not found
```

What do I need in order to properly install this version of Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24963/unable-to-install-gazebo-9.13/) by [KimJensen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26126/kimjensen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-04-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You need to [add the osrf repo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install) to your computer. Then you'll get the latest stable release (which is 9.13.0 atm).

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KimJensen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26126/kimjensen/) on 2020-04-29**:
Thank you, this solved my problem. Had to use `sudo apt upgrade` before being able to run Gazebo again, but otherwise it worked perfectly.